# Insert text inside html id after clicking a button (without javascript)

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to include some text inside a textbox (ID=button3) after pressing a button.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="collapse2" style="display:none">
   <span id="button3">text before pressing the button></span>
</div>
```

And inside javascript I know I can solve my problem in two different ways.

Option 1:

```
var element=document.getElementById("button3");
element.innerHTML="text after pressing the button";
```

Option 2:

```
$('#button3').text('text after pressing the button');
```

Can you give me a 3rd option with razor/html helpers? This is related with another question I posted yesterday ([My other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913070/cant-write-razor-variable-inside-html-id-class-element-dinamically)). However, I think this time I was able to explain my problem in a better way.

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript.

Comment: If you _really_ don't want to use Javascript, that means you need to button to do a submit, right? And do all program logic on the server side? (This may go without saying, but you didn't make it very clear in your question.)

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, thank you for your answer! Yes, I need a button to do a submit, but on the other hand, I need to insert a model value (razor) inside that ID after clicking. I've just posted one last post explaining my problem in one even simpler way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933961/inserting-model-string-in-span-text-after-button-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this entirely within razor, you will be required to make a call to the server. To do this, make your view strongly typed and take the button3 value from the model using razor.

Add an input parameter (string button3Value="initial value") to your Controller Method. Default this to your initial button3 value.

You can then use an @Html.ActionLink and pass the new button3 value from your buttonclick. This will reload the page with the appropriate value.

Answer (score -1):

u can use this option

```
$('#button3').html('text after pressing the button');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort but that one doesn't help... I really want razor/htmlhelper class