# Inserting model string in span text after button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using razor it's easy to show the values of a list in html:

```
<div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
@{
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <text> <strong>::: @i.City, @i.Country :::</strong> </text>
        <p style="margin-bottom:0px"></p>

        foreach (var h in i.Weather)
        {
            {
                <div id="MyDiv2">
                    <strong><small>@DateTime.Now.AddDays(count).ToString("dd/MM/yy")</small></strong>
                    <p style="margin-bottom:0px"></p>
                    <text><small>Max: @i.MaxTemp.ElementAt(@count)°</small></text>
                    <p style="margin-bottom:0px"></p>
                    <text><small>Min: @i.MinTemp.ElementAt(@count)°</small></text>
                    <span id="MyTest">the min temp: @i.MinTemp.ElementAt(0) </span>
                </div>
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
</div>
```

Yes, piece of cake. But know imagine that I want to change the text inside the span MyTest after clicking a button so that it has instead: "the max temp: @i.MaxTemp.ElementAt(0)".

My problem is that I would have to mix jQuery (for the button) and razor (to get the maxtemp value). Any help/tip is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
@{
    int mycounter=0;
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <text> <strong>::: @i.City, @i.Country :::</strong> </text>
        <p style="margin-bottom:0px"></p>

        foreach (var h in i.Weather)
        {
            {
                <div id="MyDiv2">
                    <strong><small>@DateTime.Now.AddDays(count).ToString("dd/MM/yy")</small></strong>
                    <p style="margin-bottom:0px"></p>
                    <text><small>Max: @i.MaxTemp.ElementAt(@count)°</small></text>
                    <p style="margin-bottom:0px"></p>
                    <text><small>Min: @i.MinTemp.ElementAt(@count)°</small></text>
                    <span maxtemp=' @i.MaxTemp.ElementAt(0)' id="MyTest">the min temp: @i.MinTemp.ElementAt(0) </span>
                </div>
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
</div>
$('#MyTest').on('click',function(){

$(this).text($(this).attr('maxtemp'));

}):
```

Comment: Your answer is not exactly what I wanted but it made me think about it in the right way.

Comment: Happy for that@LuisGouveia

Comment: Perhaps you can help me with another question that came into my mind after reading your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934684/mvc-the-right-compromise-between-browser-speed-and-respecting-the-model