# The right compromise between "browser speed" and "respecting the model"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been creating a Google Maps API MVC5 application for the past weeks.

I know that I should keep all the logic inside the controller, but I have the following doubt: In my main View I have a button called "Avoid tolls". By pressing that button the user will see the route distances calculated previously in the controller (both with and without tolls).

My question is: Why should I get the route's distances in the controller (xml service) with and without tolls when I could do that inside the View ONLY if the user wanted to check the route distance without tolls? I feel I'm loosing time accessing information (xml service) that most likely will not be demanded by the user.

Perhaps there's a way to make the view go back to the controller by the time the button is pressed. Is that it?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but I have 2 options: A) Get all distances in the controller and B) Get the "avoid tolls" distance in the view by the time the user presses the button. Which option is better?

Comment: "I know that I should keep all the logic inside the controller" ... Who told you that? Quite the opposite, in fact: your controller should have *as little logic as possible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hook the button upto an ajax request in javascript and request the additional info from the server then update your view based on the result.

Comment: Hi Matt, that's what I was trying to do but I thought about calculating everything in the controller because it would be easier. I will accept your answer but I would highly appreciate if you could check my main doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932253/insert-text-inside-html-id-after-clicking-a-button-without-javascript